# Why are there extra deform bones in rigify armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

I'm working on a rigify armature and noticed when I generated the rig it forms extra deform bones in the arms and legs. I'm fairly new to this add-on so I'm not sure why this happens. Is there a way to remove these bones and have the armature work properly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are a lot more bones in the rigify armature than there are in the metarig.  The metarig exists only to guide the placement of the actual bones.  The bones you're showing are twist bones, which are used to prevent Y axis rotation at the shoulder and groin, which usually improves apparent deformation.

Comment: Example for the twist bones: Look at your hand and forearm. Now, turn your hand around (180°) and have a look at your forearm. The forearm at the wrist turns around with the hand but at the elbow it doesn't turn at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said, this is to improve your weight painting in case of mesh flipping issues during twist movments.
You can modify the number of limb segments produced by the metarig in Bone Properties > Rigify Type.
For example, if I set the left arm Limb Segments to 1:

[image]

The metarig will produce a rig with 2 segments per metarig bone for the right arm and only one for the left:

[image]