# Trouble rigging a wrist to twist correctly

Tags: rigging, bones

I am having a lot of trouble getting a wrist to twist correctly. My bone setup is thus:
Forearm > IK palm bone, with a wrist twist bone that has the forearm as a parent and inherits rotation from the IK palm bone.
The palm cannot rotate without ruining the wrist. I have tried removing weight paint from the forearm, and moving around the bones in edit mode, but it remains broken.
[image: Bone Setup]
[image: Broken wrist]

This is the blend file, I have only been working on the right arm:
https://file.io/m4gZoHqewydA

Comment: Could you attach the blend file,please? This would help to clarify the problem/

Comment: A common technique to get a natural twist of the limbs is to subdivide the bones. This way you have 2 upper arm bones, 2 forearm bones, and so on.  The two bones can both rotate to a certain degree, allowing the hand to rotate almost 180 degrees. [Rigify does this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/235254/107598) and you can build [your own rig](https://youtu.be/j_Buujl3HvI) like this.

Comment: Thanks all, I was able to make it work using Rigify per @Blunder's answer. Very good addon.